# UFT 12.02 - Multiselect weblistbox appears values selected but dependent objects not populated

Tags: vbscript, hp-uft

The development is done in angular js and am using UFT(QTP)12.02 for test automation. Using **select and extend select** for the items in the weblist appears like selected(the selected items are gray) but the dependent controls are not being populated.
 Also tried this ,but no luck

```
Setting.WebPackage("ReplayType") = 2
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
 WshShell.SendKeys Datatable.Value("AssignedTerminal", dtlocalsheet)
 WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
 Set WshShell = Nothing
 Setting.WebPackage("ReplayType") = 1
```

Comment: Have you tried recording the process in UFT and seeing what code is generated on the multi select action?  It would also help if you give the code that isn't working as well as the code you tried to use to fix it.....

Comment: You might want to use [**FireEvent**](https://www.joecolantonio.com/2011/06/07/qtp-how-to-use-the-fireevent-method-when-a-click-does-not-work/).

Comment: Thanks Manish. I have tried all kinds of FireEvents too, but no luck

Comment: When I recorded, it did the select and extend select. Even  the recorded on could not be played back successfully, meaning the dependent weblist is not populated based on the selection in this one

Comment: Can you update your post with FireEvent part?